# Как передавать классы сущности (@Entity) в generic классы

Tags: java, java-ee

Есть три класса:

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
...
}


public abstract class AbstractFacade<T extends Object> {

   private Class<T> entityClass;

   protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

   public T getEntityByLogin(String login) {
      ...
      return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
   }
}


@Stateless
public class ClientBean extends AbstractFacade<Client> implements ClientBeanRemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    ...
    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

При работе сервера при обращении за данными вылетает ошибка, до этого весь код был написан в классе `ClientBean` и работал.

```
Warning:
StandardWrapperValve[api.service.ApplicationConfig]:
Servlet.service() for servlet api.service.ApplicationConfig 
threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity bean class: null,
please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:707)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:588)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:342)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена забыл инициализировать переменную `entityClass;`

```
public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}
```